socket.to(room).emit() not emitting events to others in the room
I want to notify other clients in a lobby when one of the clients leaves. For that I'm using socket.to(room).emit() but it is not working as expected.
I have written code in my client side to join another client's lobby/room. It emits a "join-lobby" event which is handled in my server as shown:
Server side
  socket.on("join-lobby", (lobby, callback) => {
    // Check whether lobby exists
    let room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(lobby)
    if (room === undefined) {
      callback(null); // send null to client
    } else {
      // Lobby exists
      socket.join(lobby); // Join another's lobby
      callback({ lobby }); // send lobby ID back to client
    }
  });

I have also added code in my client side to leave a lobby. It emits a "request-leave" event which is handled as shown:
Server side
  socket.on("request-leave", (lobby) => {
    socket.to(lobby).emit("leave-notify")
  });

Here, socket.to(lobby).emit() is not emitting the event to other clients in that lobby.
I have already verified that the lobby has other clients joined in it. What could be the issue?
As a workaround I'm manually emitting an event to other clients like this:
  socket.on("request-leave", (lobby) => {
    io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(lobby).forEach(clientId => {
      if(clientId !== socket.id) io.to(clientId).emit("leave-notify") // this does work
    })
  });

Complete server code:
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const port = 3000;

const server = createServer();
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`${socket.id} connected`);

  socket.emit("get-id", socket.id);

  socket.on("join-lobby", (lobby, callback) => {
    // Check whether lobby exists
    let room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(lobby)
    if (room === undefined) {
      callback(null);
    } else {
      // Lobby exists
      socket.join(lobby); // Join another's lobby
      socket.to(lobby).emit("get-opponent", socket.id); // Notify other players in the lobby
      callback({ lobby });
    }
  });

  socket.on("request-leave", (lobby) => {
    socket.to(lobby).emit("leave-notify")
  });

  // works
  // socket.on("request-leave", (lobby) => {
  //   io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(lobby).forEach(clientId => {
  //     if(clientId !== socket.id) io.to(clientId).emit("leave-notify")
  //   })
  // });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});


EDIT 1
The weird thing is that if I use socket.to(<room-id>).emit() after socket.join(lobby), the event is emitted to others. Example -
socket.on("join-lobby", (lobby, callback) => {
    // Check whether lobby exists
    let room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(lobby)
    if (room === undefined) {
      callback(null); // send null to client
    } else {
      // Lobby exists
      socket.join(lobby); // Join another's lobby
      socket.to(lobby).emit("get-opponent", socket.id); // This somehow works
      callback({ lobby }); // send lobby ID back to client
    }
  });


because you have to use io.in(<room-id>).emit(...) not socket.to(...)

@bogdanoff io.in(<room-id>).emit(...) emits the event to the sender as well. I want to emit the event to everyone in the room except the sender.

then i think there is issue with room creation, try replacing  "join-lobby" function body with socket.join(lobby); callback({ lobby }); (discard that if-else statement)

You have to use   socket.broadcast.to    in your code   like this
socket.on("request-leave", (lobby) => {
socket.broadcast.to(lobby).emit("leave-notify");
});

@vrobbi socket.to() already uses broadcast. Thanks for replying though. I've think I've found the solution to my problem and added that as an answer to this post.

Yes, of course  room name have to be always different than socket id

I use socket.on('disconnecting', (event) => {
on server side.
The follow code works perfectly in one my web app:
socket.on('disconnecting', (event) => {
  // const rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(rooms));

  for (var room of socket.rooms) {
     if (room !== socket.id) {
        // socket.to(room).emit("user has left", socket.id);
        console.log('Disconnected from room: ' + room);
        break;
     }
  }
  var numberusers = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room).size;

  if (numberusers > 1) {
     numberusers = numberusers - 1;

  }

  //  setTimeout(function (room,numberusers) {
  //  const rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);


  // var numberusers = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room).size;



  var usersnumber = '<span style="color:green">USERS IN THIS ROOM ' + numberusers + '</span><br />';
  io.in(room).emit('numberusers', {
     'numberusers': usersnumber
  });

  //  }, 1000);

});

Sorry to say this but this does not answer my question.

After some trial and error, I've found that using socket.to(<room-id>).emit(<event-name>) where the room-id is the same as the socket id of another client, it tends to send a private message to that client.
EDIT 1 - Continuing the last paragraph, if the socket with id same as that of the room uses socket.to().emit(), for some reason it doesn't emit the event to others in the room.
This is likely because of the concept of public rooms and private rooms which I couldn't find in the documentation. I came across it when I was using the Admin UI provided by Socket.IO.
Previous approach:
If client A wants to join client B's room, A joins the room corresponding to B's socket id. However, doing so, A joins B's private room. The Admin UI confirms this.
New approach:
B first creates a room (handled by the server using socket.join(<room-name>)) having a name different from their socket id. This creates a public room with the room name provided. Now A can join B's room using the same room name.
With the new approach, socket.to(<room>).emit(<event>) works as expected.
